# linq where list contains all matched in list

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework-6

I have three tables Keyword, Product and KeywordProduct.

- If I try to filter "the", return A and B products
- If I try to filter "matrix", return only B product

but when I filter "the matrix", I get B and A too. I need to get only B record.

that is the code:

```cs
var keywordTermList = ("the matrix").Split(' ');

db.Products
.Where(product => product.ProductKeywords.All(k => keywordTermList.Contains(k.Keyword.Name)))
```

Keyword Table

```
+-----------+---------+
| KeywordId |  Name   |
+-----------+---------+
|         1 | awakens |
|         2 | force   |
|         3 | the     |
|         4 | matrix  |
+-----------+---------+
```

ProductKeyword Table

```
+------------+-----------+
| KeywordId  | ProductId |
+------------+-----------+
| 3(the)     | A         |
| 2(force)   | A         |
| 1(awakens) | A         |
| 3(the)     | B         |
| 4(matrix)  | B         |
+------------+-----------+
```

Product Table has A and B records.

How would I go about this? How can I get only B when I filter "the matrix".

Comment: `var keywordTermList = searchString.Split(' ').Where(t => !ignore.Contains(t)).toList();` -- where `ignore` is a list of `{ "a", "an", "the", ... }` and whatever else you want to ignore.

Comment: Yes, I know it. That's just sample records.

Comment: The above doesn't seem to be your real query, because it most likely to filter more data (for instance if product B has third word) than returning more records.

Comment: You're rigth. That's gonna happen...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the subset to fully match the surperset

```
var query = products.Where(p => !keywordListTerm.Except(p.ProductKeywords.Select(pk => pk.Name)).Any());
```

Here is full example

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

        Product A = new Product();
        A.Name = "A";
        A.ProductKeywords = new List<Keyword>() { 
            new Keyword(){Name = "the"},
            new Keyword(){Name = "force"},
            new Keyword(){Name = "awakens"}
        };

        Product B = new Product();
        B.Name = "B";
        B.ProductKeywords = new List<Keyword>() { 
            new Keyword(){Name = "the"},
            new Keyword(){Name = "matrix"}
        };

        List<Product> products = new List<Product>() { A, B };

        var keywordListTerm = ("the force matrix").Split(' ');

        var query = products.Where(p => !keywordListTerm.Except(p.ProductKeywords.Select(pk => pk.Name)).Any());

        foreach (var item in query) { 
            Console.WriteLine(item.Name);
        }

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Product {
    public string Name = string.Empty;
    public List<Keyword> ProductKeywords;
}

public class Keyword
{
    public string Name;

}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: While this is technically correct for general LINQ, I don't know if you noticed the `entity-framework-6` tag, so the above cannot be translated to SQL query and will fail with runtime exception.

Comment: @IvanStoev Oh! I did not know that not all the LINQ can be translated to SQL successfully. Not sure how it is working for the OP.

Comment: Yeah, that's strange - if it works for him, why not accepting it :/ But that's not our problem I guess :)

Comment: If you know better solution, please let me know guys. I don't wanna face any future problem.

Comment: @tsubasaetkisi have u run the above query in the EF6 set up? Is it working?

Comment: Okay. You should accept it as answer then so that others would know this is the answer to the question unless, you get a better answer from others. Thanks.